# Find the smallest common multiple

Tags: javascript

well i hope you can understand me. I want to get the the smallest common multiple between the range of number i give to the function, for example if i put looker(1,3) the function will look for the smallest common multiple in 1,2,3 that's the range, and the answer it's 6, i dunno if get it.
this is a challenge from freecodecamp, the problem it's that when i run function with the with the range (1,3) it works, (1,5) it works, but with other ranges the google console says "rende process gone".

```
const looker = (arra) => {
var nume = [];
var status = "no";
var statusN = 0;
var array = [];
var mul = [];
var contador = arra[1];
var aumentador = 2;

while(contador > arra[0] - 1) {
    array.push(contador);
    mul.push(contador);
    nume.push(contador);
    contador--;
}
// console.log(nume);
// console.log(array);
// console.log(mul);
// console.log(contador);

while(contador != arra[1]) {
    for(let x of nume) {
        array.push(x*aumentador);
        mul.push(x*aumentador);
    }
    aumentador++;

    for(let a of mul) {
        for(let i of array) {
            if(a == i) {
                contador++;
            }
        }

        if(contador == arra[1]) {
            status = "si"
            statusN = a;
            break;
        } else {
            status = "no";
            contador = 0;
        }
    }
}

if(status == "si") {
    console.log(`el numero que se repite es ${statusN}`);
} else {
    console.log(`ningun numero se repite ${arra[1]} veces`);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want something like this ..**

```js
function findGCD() {
  if($("#first").val() != null && $("#second").val() != null ){
    let fn = parseInt($("#first").val());
    let sn = parseInt($("#second").val());
    let gcd = lcm_two_numbers(fn, sn);
    $("#answer").html("Smallest common multiple : " + gcd)
  }
}

function lcm_two_numbers(x, y) {
   if ((typeof x !== 'number') || (typeof y !== 'number')) 
    return false;
  return (!x || !y) ? 0 : Math.abs((x * y) / gcd_two_numbers(x, y));
}

function gcd_two_numbers(x, y) {
  x = Math.abs(x);
  y = Math.abs(y);
  while(y) {
    var t = y;
    y = x % y;
    x = t;
  }
  return x;
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0095ff;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
 font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="first">First number:</label>
<input type="number" id="first" name="first" min="1" max="5">
<label for="second">Second number:</label>
<input type="number" id="second" name="second" min="1" max="5">
<button  onclick="findGCD()">GCD</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```